# Python OpenSearch retrieve records based on element in a list

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

So I need to retrieve records based on a field called "cash_transfer_ids" which is a python list.
I want to retrieve all records whose cash_transfer_ids contain a specific id value (a string).
What should the query be look like? Should I use match or term query?

Example: I want to retrieve any record whose cash_transfer_ids field contains 'abc'
Then I may get record such as
record 1: cash_transfer_ids:['abc']
record 2: cash_transfer_ids:['dfdfd', 'abc']
etc...

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

if cash_transfer_ids is type keyword I try filter with Term.

```
   term = "abc"
    query = {
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "cash_transfer_ids": {
                    "value": term
                  }
                }
              }
            }
    response = get_client_es().search(index="idx_test", body=query)
```